# Accessing Form Data on Classic Asp using server side Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, validation, post, asp-classic

I am tying to implement server side validation of a html form using asp javascript, and I am running into some unexpected behavior..my asp and html code is below:

```
<%
var bread = String(Request.Form("bread"));
if (!bread)
    Response.Write("Choose a bread!");
%>
<br/>

    <select id="breadDropDown" name="bread">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="white">white</option>
        <option value="wheat">wheat</option>
        <option value="flatbread">flatbread</option>
    </select>

</div>
```

here I am getting the behavior I want, that is on GET nothing is written, and on invalid POST the error is written.

```
<%
var meat = String(Request.Form("meat"));
if (!meat)
    Response.Write("Choose a meat!");
%>
<br/>

    <input type="checkbox" name="meat" value="turkey">turkey</input><br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="meat" value="ham">ham</input><br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="meat" value="roast beef">roast beef</input><br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="meat" value="double meat">double meat</input><br />

</div>
```

However when I am using a group of checkboxes instead of a select box I am getting incorrect behavior..i.e. no error is being written.

Any insight would be helpful as there is not an abundance of resources for classis asp with javascript that I could find.

Thanks!

Comment: `Request.Form("meat")` will probably be a collection/array. Have you tried to debug what `String(Request.form("meat"))` look like?

Answer (score 0):

Request.Form("meat") will give you undefined

Request("meat") will give you the values that are checked in a comma seperated string (eg. turkey, ham)

Answer (score 0):

I've always thought you need to put a form tag around your input tags.

```
<form name='frmFood' id='frmFood' method='post'>
<input or select>
</form>
```

Comment: Input tags outside of forms are valid, well-formed HTML. See http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.2.1

Answer (score 0):

The two existing answers here from Graham and ScotterMonkey sort of touch on the underlying issue, but I will try to synthesize them more completely and with a bit of helpful context.

ASP Classic provides a `Request` object which has as properties several kinds of Collections, such as:

```
Request.Form

Request.QueryString

Request.ServerVariables
```

In the code provided with the original question, you are trying to access `Request.Form("meat")`.  However ASP's `Request.Form` collection is only populated via the submission of an HTML **form element**, and because no HTML **form element** is declared in the HTML portion of the code, `Request.Form` has nothing to access.

However, as user Graham pointed out, it appears as though the `Request` object is able to access HTML elements of the requesting page via their associated `name` attribute.  For this reason, accessing `Request("meat")` returns a list of each element on the page with a name attribute corresponding to "meat".

The Microsoft documentation on ASP's built in Request Object is helpful in following through this type of older code. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms524948(v=vs.90)